# If NVD CVE description contains filenames, does it mean the referred project is open sourced?

Tags: security, open-source

I'm trying to find as many as possible the open source project repos for future vulnerability research. While playing with the NVD feed data, I found some of the CVE descriptions contains filename or even function name of the source code that has caused the vulnerability, does it mean the projects are open sourced?

Meanwhile, is there any better way or data source that could help me actually get the referred projects repos? (e.g. CVE-2018-13305 --> FFmpeg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to your first question is no. The NVD data is based on the CVE record from MiTRE. Once MiTRE has released the details of the CVE, details as submitted by the CVE requester or the CNA, NVD will then perform additional analysis.

If the CVE requester/CNA provides details such as filename/function, then it will be in the CVE record, or if the NVD is able to determine those details from publicly available sources, then they may add it to their analysis. That said, you'll find it extremely rare that closed-source CVEs have that type of detail.

So while the fact that the CVE description contains filenames or functions is a good indicator that the software in question is open source, it is not a rule.

The answer to your second question is no. Well, there are ways, but that's far too broad of a question to address here.

Answer (score 0):

To address your first question, it may, it may not. I have seen description of non-open-source vulnerabilities that list the file/module/function names that are vulnerable.

To answer your second question, yes, there is a way. In the NVD JSON feeds, you'll see that every vulnerability has reference to vendor adversaries and other external references online. In the reference links field, your see the fields url and tags (url is the URI and the tags is the description of the URL). To achieve the goal that you desire, I would start with finding all the vulnerabilities that link to commits on git repositories (TIP: not only github). Next, you can see which among those git references, filter all those that link to other non-open-source vulnerability POCs.